# diamagnetism in constant magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

"The diamagnetic materials repel the materials which produces magnetic field, so putting these materials in the proximity of the magnetic field generating materials produces the effect of the diamagnetic levitation."

I read this statement somewhere and I got confused with it.

I know that when magnetic field is applied to a current carrying loop an electric potential is induced in the circuit which is proportional to rate of change of the magnetic flux through the loop. This induced potential gives raise to a current flow in such a direction so that the magnetic field generated because of this new current is in opposition of the applied magnetic field which is diamagnetism.

I want to know what happens to the diamagnetic material when it is kept in a constant magnetic field. Since the field is constant now, there would not be any flux change and hence no induced magnetic field to oppose the constant applied field. So will in that case be no diamagnetic effect or any other effect?

Comment: Diamagnetism, like paramagnetism and ferro-magnetism, is a static effect.  It only depends on the strength of the B field and not the rate of change.  I like to think of it this way, there are little magnets inside every atom.  In paramagnetic materials the little atom magnets like to line up with the B-field.  And this makes the B field in the material a bit larger than the applied field.  In diamagnetic  materials the little atom magnets are in a lower energy state if they line up anti-parallel with the applied field.  This makes the field in the materiel a bit less.